# how to do a fade-in effect for one layer after another layer, CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, cabasicanimation

I am currently having 3 images and my goal is to fade in one layer after another, so first one fades in then second and the last one.Done

What I am doing is

```
for (UIImageView *imageView in arr) {
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.fromValue =   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    animation.toValue   =   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    animation.duration  =   4;
    animation.removedOnCompletion   =   NO;
    animation.fillMode  =   kCAFillModeBoth;
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacityAnimation"];
}
```

However, this is just to fade in all of layer at the same time.  What should I do in order to display them in order.

Answer (score 0):

Tag your image views with e.g. 10, 20, 30. Then,

```
-(void)addAnimationToView:(UIView*)image {
  CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
  animation.fromValue =   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
  animation.toValue   =   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
  animation.duration  =   4;
  animation.removedOnCompletion   =   NO;
  animation.fillMode  =   kCAFillModeBoth;
  [imageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacityAnimation"];
}

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
  UIImageView *image = (UIImageView*) [self.view viewWithTag:(i+1)*10];
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
         i*4 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    [self addAnimationToView:image];
  });
}
```

Maybe you have to prefix the definition of `image` with `__block` but I think it is not necessary.

There is another way to do it with the `CAMediaTiming` protocol, but maybe that is more code than this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use performselector:afterDelay to perform fading in appropriate order.